# FusionCharts + Prototype Modalbox + Google Chrome = Browser View Bug

Tags: google-chrome, prototype, modal-dialog, fusioncharts

I am hoping that someone can help shed some light on the underlying issue causing the bug that you see here:

[image]

As you can see, the FusionChart is incorrecly overlaying on top of the Modalbox when the it is opened.  This issue only occurs in Google Chrome.  All other browsers are ok.

Any ideas on the underlying issue here?  And what can be done?

Comment: Any chance of a URL, possibly to just a test page that exhibits the bug?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Step by step of what to click? I went to the site but I ain't going to search for your error especially since your website tends to lag at some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I messed with overlaying a div on top of Flash (What is going on here) I could get it to work on all platforms except Linux. Are you using a Linux distribution? If not the solution is usually to add wmode="transparent" to the embed.

Otherwise, the only solution is to set .style.display="none"; on the FusionChart whenever the Modalbox is shown and .style.display=""; when the Modalbox is closed.

Answer (score 2):

When Flash objects appear on top of every other HTML elements, it is most likely because the window mode (wMode) parameter of the Flash  movie is set to "window".

In FusionCharts, one can set wMode in two ways:

**A. Using `.setTransparent()` JavaScript function**

`setTransparent(false)` changes the window mode to "opaque" and that solves the issue of FusionCharts appearing on top of modal windows and lightboxes.

`setTransparent(true)` also serves the same purpose. It sets wMode to "transparent". (Any value for wMode, except "window" would do the trick.)

Example JavaScript:

```
var myChart = new FusionCharts( "FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", 
      "myChartId", "400", "300", "0", "1" );
  myChart.setXMLUrl("Data.xml");
  myChart.setTransparent(false); // set wMode to opaque
  myChart.render("chartContainer");
```

Since FusionCharts 3.2, setting `setTransparent(null)` restores wMode to "window" and you would NOT want to do that for your case! :)

**B. Using `wMode` property during new FusionCharts construction**

Also since FusionCharts 3.2 introduced object-style construction method, the value of wMode can be provided while doing `new FusionCharts(...)` itself by providing `wMode: 'opaque'`